# Why is this CSS selector not working?

Tags: html, css

Am I going crazy? Shouldn't the styles I applied to '.firstDiv' cause a yellow box to appear? Seems like very simple code and I'm not sure what's going wrong. When I hit 'Run,' I don't see the yellow div appear.

http://jsfiddle.net/uwf5e5eu/

HTML:

```
<div class=“firstDiv”>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
  .firstDiv { 
  height: 500px; 
  background-color: yellow; 
  width: 500px; 
}
```

Comment: It looks like the quotes around the attribute value are wrong. `”` -> `"`... [Updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/aj25se1c/)

Comment: Are you writing code is MS Word or something?

Comment: @takendarkk Most likely TextEdit on iOS.

Comment: Oy! Thanks for your help everyone. Yes, I was using TextEdit on my Air. Didn't realize it was formatting quotes differently. Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

You use wrong symbol for quotes.

Use this: `"` instead of this: `”`.

Correct HTML:

```
<div class="firstDiv">

</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uwf5e5eu/8/)

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew it had to be something small

Comment: @WeCareALot You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong character for quoting: use " not “

```
<div class="firstDiv">

</div>
```